Syntax error when rails tries to create ar_internal_metadata?
after upgrating from rails 5.2 to rails 6.1 and ruby 2.7.2 to 3.3.5 I'm facing some weird errors syntax errors when running the initial migration. The application runs fine and even run the migrations if the table ar_internal_metadata has been created in the previous rails version (tried breaking the first migration and running db:migrate to see the difference between versions. On 5.2 it creates both schema_migrations and ar_internal_metadata, while on 6.1 it only creates schema_migrations and throws an exception)
The error I see when running rails db:migrate is this:
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: ...ter varying, "created_at" timestamp with time zone(6) NOT NU...
                                                             ^
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:49:in `exec'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:48:in `block in execute'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:696:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:695:in `block in log'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:687:in `log'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:47:in `execute'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:322:in `create_table'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.8/lib/active_record/internal_metadata.rb:49:in `create_table'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1229:in `initialize'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1086:in `new'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1086:in `up'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1061:in `migrate'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.8/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `migrate'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.8/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.8/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:24:in `block in perform'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:59:in `with_application'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.8/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.8/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:75:in `require'
/home/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

and this is my gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?('/')
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

ruby '3.3.5'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.1', '>= 6.1.7.8'
gem 'pg', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.8'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sassc-rails'
gem 'terser'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'recaptcha'
gem 'deep_cloneable', '~> 3.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.142'
  gem 'database_cleaner-active_record'
  gem 'capybara-select2'
  gem 'webmock'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'uniform_notifier'
  gem 'bullet'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'fake_ftp', '~> 0.3.0'
  gem 'readapt'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'capistrano', '= 3.14.1', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.3', require: false
  gem 'capistrano3-puma', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm', require: false
  gem 'rufo'
  gem 'htmlbeautifier'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 7.0', '>= 7.0.9'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap4'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'datetime_picker_rails', '~> 0.0.7'
gem 'cpf_cnpj'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_token_auth'
gem 'pundit', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.1'
gem 'activesupport-decorators', '~> 2.1'
gem 'rufus-scheduler', '~> 3.4.0'
gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
gem 'ros-apartment', require: 'apartment'
gem "sidekiq", "~> 6.4.0"
gem 'ros-apartment-sidekiq', require: 'apartment-sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-cron'
gem 'sidekiq-status'
gem 'activejob-uniqueness', require: 'active_job/uniqueness/sidekiq_patch'
gem 'sendgrid-ruby'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '~> 0.12.6'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'correios-cep'
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 6.1', '>= 6.1.5'
gem 'rails_db', '~> 2.3', '>= 2.3.1'
gem 'roo', '~> 2.7', '>= 2.7.1'
gem 'caxlsx'
gem 'caxlsx_rails'
gem 'combine_pdf', '1.0.15'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3'
gem 'awesome_print'
gem 'dropbox_api', '~> 0.1.17'
gem 'fast_jsonapi'
gem 'date_validator', '~> 0.9.0'
gem 'audited', '~> 4.9'
gem 'exception_handler', '~> 0.8.0.0'
gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'slack-notifier'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'rack-cors'
gem 'dotiw', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.1'
gem 'ean'
gem 'discordrb', '~> 3.4'
gem 'rake', '= 13.0.3'
gem 'net-ftp'
gem 'net-sftp'
gem 'rubyzip'
gem 'ajax-datatables-rails'
gem 'rack-attack'
gem 'timecop'
gem "viacep"
gem 'oj', '3.12.3'
gem 'bigdecimal', '2.0.2'
gem "inertia_rails", "~> 3.2"
gem "vite_rails"
gem 'overmind', '~> 2.5', '>= 2.5.1'

Any idea on what might be happening?

That's not valid SQL, (6) should be between timestamp and with time zone and not after.

Yeah, I know. And that's exactly them problem. That sql is not my code

What part of your code does create the SQL code? That's where the bug is. Could you contact the people who wrote that code and report this bug?

Its not my code that generates that sql. I did post in the gem's git, but since I have no idea how to reproduce this problem, it will most likely be closed :(

The combination of Rails 6 and Ruby 3.3 is probably where the issue lies.

@dbugger while you're right that Rails 6.1.Z is only really compatible with 3.0.Z I can't see how that would generate the invalid SQL.

You have a lot of cruft in that gemfile. I would start by removing all the gems that are bundled with Ruby such as net-ftp, rake and bigdecimal. Also move the gems that are just for test/dev like timecop into the relevant groups.

@max - some weird parameter passing combo is my hunch.

moved to ruby 3.0.7 and removed all gems that already exist for ruby but the issue persists

Make sure you're running the right version of migration for the rails version.  Although the comments above might be valuable.  I have upgraded two RoR applications from rails 3.0.2 and 3.2 both to 7.x rails and ruby 1.9.3 to 3.2.2.  I didn't start using Ruby 3.x until I got to Rails 7.  Also, check out FastRuby.io, lots of info there about upgrading rails applications.

Can you talk more about "right version of migration"? not sure what that means
